# Unexpected recycles of IIS.Net Application Pool

Tags: iis, asp.net, application-pools

Since June 19 we are experiencing unexplained and undesired recycles of Application Pool worker processes.
The Application Pool has a scheduled 3am recycle. But since June 19th we are experiencing additional unexplained daily recycles between 5am and 5:30am. We are not yet able to find the cause or trigger. Not in the IIS Admin settings nor in the Event Logs nor in the Task Scheduler.

We luckily do have a call stack of the recycle, sent by email of IIS Admin:

```
Current StackTrace (max 30 frames deep):
    0.  ezWeb.Global_asax.Application_End()
    1.  System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod()
    2.  System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal()
    3.  System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke()
    4.  System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke()
    5.  System.Web.HttpApplication.InvokeMethodWithAssert()
    6.  System.Web.HttpApplication.ProcessSpecialRequest()
    7.  System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireApplicationOnEnd()
    8.  System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.Dispose()
    9.  System.Web.HttpRuntime.Dispose()
    10. System.Web.HttpRuntime.ReleaseResourcesAndUnloadAppDomain()
    11. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal()
    12. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run()
    13. System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
    14. System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Where should we further search for the cause, the trigger of this recycle?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be Kaspersky antivirus.
After my intensive research and an email support exchange with them it became clear that the daily early morning file system scan was "touching" the files in the ASP.Net bin directory, in a very vague manner (changing and restoring file dates). See this Kaspersky support post:

https://forum.kaspersky.com/index.php?/topic/396144-kavfswpexe-causing-mass-file-change-events-by-design/

They provided a fix for it.